# share node_modules directory across multiple projects

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular,I want to use node_modules, assume which exist in D:\MySampleProject and I want to use same node_modules in E:\TestProject as well.Without using npm install (I have used 'mklink /j node_modules' it does not work) is there any possible way.Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can share a node_modules directory amongst projects.

From node's documentation:

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module,
>   and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then node starts at the
>   parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and
>   attempts to load the module from that location.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and
>   so on, until the root of the file system is reached.
>
> For example, if the file at '/home/ry/projects/foo.js' called
>   require('bar.js'), then node would look in the following locations, in
>   this order:
>
> /home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js /home/ry/node_modules/bar.js
>   /home/node_modules/bar.js /node_modules/bar.js

So just put a node_modules folder inside your projects directory and put in whatever modules you want. Just require them like normal. When node doesn't find a node_modules directory in your project folder, it will check the parent folder automatically. So make your directory structure like this:

-myProjects

--node_modules

--myproject1

---sub-project

--myproject2

So like this, even your sub-project's dependencies can draw on your main node_modules repository.

One drawback to doing it this way is you will have to build out your package.json file manually (unless someone knows a way to automate this with grunt or something). When you install your packages and add the --save arg to an npm install command it automatically appends it to the dependencies section or your package.json, which is convenient.

Comment: Thanks for reply..It seems project with in the projects means sub projects.But my approach is different.I dont want to use again npm install

Comment: multiple project with in one solution?